# create single dataframe by reading multiple html files

Tags: python, html, arrays, list

I have 23 html files, which contain data in same tabular format, i want to create dataframe of all files and consolidate in one big dataframe for further analysis, below is the code,

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_rec = glob.glob('D:\python\*.html')
#print(all_rec)
list_data = []

for filename in all_rec:
    data = pd.read_html(filename)
    list_data.append(data)

list_data # sample output from t files

[[                   start_time                    user_host       query_time  \
  0  2020-02-19 07:01:56.411155  lrdba[lrdba] @ localhost []  00:01:55.299187   
  1  2020-02-20 07:01:56.005284  lrdba[lrdba] @ localhost []  00:01:54.210222   

             db                                    sql_text  
  0  kvb  call PROC_PROCESSINGSUMMARY(null,null)  
  1  kvb  call PROC_PROCESSINGSUMMARY(null,null)  ],
 [                   start_time                    user_host       query_time  \
  0  2020-02-19 07:01:56.411155  lrdba[lrdba] @ localhost []  00:01:55.299187   
  1  2020-02-20 07:01:56.005284  lrdba[lrdba] @ localhost []  00:01:54.210222   

             db                                    sql_text  
  0  kvb  call PROC_PROCESSINGSUMMARY(null,null)  
  1  kvb  call PROC_PROCESSINGSUMMARY(null,null)  ]]    

list_data =list_data[0] #when i mention this list_data[0] it show data for first file 
list_data =list_data[-1] #for list_data[-1] it show data for last file for below code

pd.concat(list_data,ignore_index=True)
```

I want to know what value i should put in [] to get all file details in one big dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_rec = glob.glob('D:\python\*.html')
#print(all_rec)
list_data = []

for filename in all_rec:
    data = pd.read_html(filename)
    list_data.append(data)

list_data # showing array of all html data  

#remove this line
list_data =list_data[0] 
#remove this line
list_data =list_data[-1] 

pd.DataFrame(list_data).reset_index(drop=True) #replace concat with DataFrame
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: Thankx Ehsan for your help..., but pd.DataFrame(list_data,ignore_index=True) is showing this error __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'

Comment: @jatin Would you try now?

Comment: hey @Ehsan...it still not work for me... it printed start_time only .., i m not able to copy/pasteit here

 0
0 start_time ...
1 start_time ...

Comment: Well I cant tell you more unless I have an idea about your data. by the way did you remove those lines that I mentioned that should be removed?

Comment: yes @ehsan, I hv removed those lines.., if u want i can send u both the file.., its a sample file which i hv created